# Kivy is not compatible with Cython?

Tags: python, installation, cython, kivy

I decided to choose kivy to to help me design my gui applications, but I am facing this problem; I installed cython 0.22 and everytime I try to install kivy I get this (with a lot of other lines):

> ImportError: Incompatible Cython Version

Is it because of Cython or Kivy?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kivy's latest release is not compatible with cython 0.22. You can fix it by installing cython 0.21, or by using the master branch and merging [this PR](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/3283).

You should get a message about this as part of the compilation process when it fails.

Comment: I tried to install cython 0.21 but it gave me another type of error this time... something about visual basic error? Could it be the kivy installation package itself? But I tried to download other versions but nothing changed..

Comment: If you're using windows, you'll probably find it easier to use the kivy portable package on the website anyway. If you want to build with cython, you need both a compatible version and some other dependencies.

Comment: Oh I got what you mean. So that means that I don't need to build but just use the kivy.bat file. Alright, thanks a lot sir.. :)